# In stock & Out of stock products are displaying randomly

Tags: database, out-of-stock, search-terms

we are using following extension in our site....

1)**Search extension** : https://mirasvit.com/magento-extensions/sphinx-search-ultimate.html . From this we can implement feature that if we search for Product all the In-stock products will display first and than out-of-stock products. Everything was fine.

Later we wanted to implement following feature.

2)**Displaying out-of-stock products at last in the listing pages**. :
https://github.com/r-martins/Magento-OutOfStockLast .

This worked fine. But Problem happened to first feature, Means **after using 2nd extension, when we search for product, than in-stock & out-of-stock products are displaying randomly.**

this is our search results page : http://videomergerapp.com/catalogsearch/result/?q=hot+wheels

when we debug this page , i can see SQL query and results: http://videomergerapp.com/catalogsearch/result/?q=hot+wheels&debug

i can see all the product ids with all in-stock product ids are displaying first and than out-of-stock products ids are displaying.

but in site [ listing page ] in-stock & out-of-stock products are displaying in random order.

Please help me what i need to do for working both features in one site.

[image]

Comment: I am also looking for similar kind of solution. Please update me if you find the solution. http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/95934/organise-search-results

Comment: @AdarshKhatri we are using sphinx seach. i will let you know once i get solution.

Comment: why you are using the both extension they have same functionality?

Comment: One extension will display in stock products on first when we search for products in search bar. another extension display in-stock products first when we click on category links.

Comment: @AdarshKhatri did you got solution for that question? in my case it was problem with collection.php in one extension.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually such behavior means that something happend to collection between the place where you debug and end result. Try to debug collection just before it is being rendered by View - for example, in catalogsearch template

Comment: we will check it.

Answer (score 1):

Contact Mirasvit they will resolve this for you. I have this and other modules, they have been absolutely fantastic in resolving any issue I have.

As a note, typically these kinds of questions get closed so its always important that you contact the developer to find a solution since its impossible for anyone to resolve this without looking at both modules.

Comment: If you cant figure it out, definitely contact them, hands down one of the best developers in terms of support and response time.

Comment: you are exactly right., I have used extensions from lot of team. For me,They are the Best extension team in support.